# Android - Reading specific part from txt file?

Tags: android, textview

I have an txt file saved on sdcard. I use this code to read text from file and it is showed in textView :

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/Bonbon info");
        dir.mkdirs();
        File f2 = new File(dir, "web_paket.txt");

        StringBuilder text2 = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f2));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text2.append(line);
                text2.append('\n');
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        }

        TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv2.setText(text2);
```

This code is working, and it reads hole file and displays it in textView. Can I read only specific part of the file, like caracters in positions 65 to 75 ??

Answer (score 1):

Put in a call to br.skip(n) before the loop starts, with n being the number of characters you want to skip. That will get you to the start of the bit you want to read. Then include a counter in your loop so you stop when you've read enough characters. Something like:

```
    br.skip(64);

    int charactersRead = 0;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && charactersRead < 10) {
                    text2.append(line);
                    text2.append('\n');
                    charactersRead++;
                }
```

See the [BufferedReader.skip() documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#skip%28long%29).

Comment: Think you want read() instead of readline() in that case, otherwise characterRead should increase by the number of chars in line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this applies for text files but for binary files it is possible to perform random access into the file. Check out this link: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html

Comment: You can use it to access any file. The only caveat is that you will get a string of bytes, and you have to convert those to text yourself. You'll need to take care of encoding/decoding, handling newlines, etc. If the file is relatively small, it might not be worth the effort though. Processing the file line by line, and skipping what you don't need is far easier.